# comparing file and folder name in python

Tags: python

I want to compare the content of a file(.txt) in which there are only IP addresses to the name of folders with are named by IP addresses. The file is present in the same directory in which the are folders present, like this

XYZ

|___ 10.25.85.10

|___ 10.02.25.11

|___ server.txt

XYZ is the main directory with two are folders and server.txt. It(server.txt) is the file in which folder names like (10.25.85.10, 10.02.25.11) are already present and one extra assume 10.0.0.0. Now I want that extra IP to get saved in a list after comparing file content and folder name. How can I solve this?

Comment: Would you like to add any code you're currently stuck on? Please add a [mcve] including the file content and expected output

Comment: What does the comparison do? What happens when there are discrepancies found between the content of `server.txt` and the actual list of IP-address-named directories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the file contents in a list however you like,

Then iterate over the list of IPs

```
import os
dir_content = os.listdir()
not_in_dir = []
ips = ["10.25.85.10", "10.02.25.11", "10.0.0.0"]
for ip in ips:
     if ip not in dir_content:
             not_in_dir.append(ip)
print(not_in_dir)
```

This will get you

```
["10.0.0.0"]
```

Hope this helps you.